# Why is my google app engine project not sending an email?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, jakarta-mail

I have uploaded a test html page and servlet following [this article](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/02/03/google-app-engine-sending-emails/) exactly. This works and will send me an email. However, when I copy this code almost exactly into my SendEmail method in the code shown below it does not send an email. I know when I run this locally that it gets to the SendEmail method just fine (but you cannot send emails using the development server in GAE). When I deploy it there are no errors on the page or in the logs so it plain old seems like it is just not sending the email. Anyone see a reason why?

```
public class EmailService {
    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy");

    public static void SendDeadlineEmails() {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            List<DeadlineEmailObject> studentsWithDeadlineToday = populateEmailList(pm);
            sendEmails(studentsWithDeadlineToday);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    private static List<DeadlineEmailObject> populateEmailList(PersistenceManager pm) {
        List<Student> students =  getStudents(pm);
        List<DeadlineEmailObject> studentsWithDeadlineToday = new ArrayList<DeadlineEmailObject>();
        String today = dateFormatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for(Student student : students) {
            Set<Charge> charges = student.getCharges();
            if(charges != null) {
                for(Charge charge : charges) {
                    String deadline = dateFormatter.format(charge.getDeadline());
                    if(deadline.equals(today)) {
                        studentsWithDeadlineToday.add(new DeadlineEmailObject(student, charge));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return studentsWithDeadlineToday;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static List<Student> getStudents(PersistenceManager pm) {
        return (List<Student>) pm.newQuery(Student.class).execute();
    }

    private static void sendEmails(List<DeadlineEmailObject> studentsWithDeadlineToday) {
        for(DeadlineEmailObject emailObj : studentsWithDeadlineToday) {
            sendEmail(emailObj);
            System.out.println("Student: " + emailObj.getStudent().getFullName() + "\nAmount: " + emailObj.getCharge().getAmount() + 
                    "\nDeadline: " + dateFormatter.format(emailObj.getCharge().getDeadline()));
        }
    }

    private static void sendEmail(DeadlineEmailObject emailObj) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("njbuwm@gmail.com", "Admin"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailObj.getStudent().getEmail(), emailObj.getStudent().getFullName()));
            msg.setSubject("Deadline Reached");
            msg.setText(buildMessage(emailObj));
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static String buildMessage(DeadlineEmailObject emailObj) {
        String email = "";
        email += "Dear " + emailObj.getStudent().getFullName() + " ,\n";
        email += "You owe us money. This much: $" + emailObj.getCharge().getAmount() + ".\n";
        email += "For this reason: " + emailObj.getCharge().getReason() + ".\n";
        email += "The deadline is today and I advise you to pay it or you will be deported to Idontpaymybills Island forever.\n";
        email += "Thank you,\n Automated Emailer";
        return email;
    }

    private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
        return JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional").getPersistenceManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it does not **send** e-mail?

Comment: Well I was assuming because I am sending it to myself and I am not receiving it.

Comment: Have you checked your **spam** folder?

Answer (score 1):

Change your call to `setFrom()` to use an email address permitted in the [**Developers Guide**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients):

> To set the sender address, the app calls the setFrom() method on the
>   MimeMessage object. The sender address must be one of the following
>   types:
>
> - The address of a registered administrator for the application
> - The address of the user for the current request signed in with a    Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address  with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by Google Apps.
> - Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as    xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).

Comment: Already is, good advice for future onlookers of this question though. It seems something was buggy because I redeployed this morning and it just worked ... black magic most likely.